# laravel app::make() returns an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, inversion-of-control

I've created a simple class `Car` which takes 2 arguments at its constructor, `Wheels` and `SteeringWheel` both of those arguments are another objects.

When I type `App::make('Car')`, as I recall, it should instantiate  a `Car` object and do the dependency injection on it's own even without binding the `Car` class. However, when I do that, I get an error: `ReflectionException: Class Car does not exist` even tho I've used the `Car` namespace by doing: `use Acme\Car` at the top of the page.

However, if I provide to the `make` function the full "path" to the `Car` class, it works: `App::make('\Acme\Car');` Any idea how I can make it work even if I type `Car` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App::make()` function doesn't use the includes at the top of the page, it creates a class from the string you provide. If you want to only use `Car`, remove the `namespace Acme` from the `Car` class.

Comment: I see. Well that's quite understandable why I guess. Thanks for clarifying my suspicion

Comment: Just to clarify something, if I was to add the `Car` class as an alias, it would be okay if I typed `Car` only? And, how come if you use a model it works? all of the models are in the global namespace?

Comment: If you don't put `namespace` in the models yourself, they are default not in a namespace/in global namespace. If you add `Car` as an alias, it should work.